# Why SQL error when insert turkish letter?

Tags: mysql, sql, laragon

I created a simple form with 3 inputs for make a new wedding.

I ask for name, password and email.

But if the user enters a Turkish letter like **marvın**, I get this error :

> Erreur SQL (1366) : Incorrect string value: '\xC4\xB1n' for column 'name' at row 1

Someone can help me please? I'm lost ..

TY !

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Colum info : VARCHAR (255)

Comment: Try nvarchar(255).

Comment: I don't have nvarchar in HeidiSQL

Comment: It seems that you are concatenating the values in the insert statement. If it is the case, then you shouldn't. You should declare an insert statement with parameters and send the values as parameter values.

Comment: Do you use prepared statements?

Comment: Yes i use prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

For the table column to accept any different letters than English I think it must have a collation so.

```
Alter table_name alter column names varchar(256) with collation Turkish..
```

Comment: I try to change collation to 'latin5_turkish_ci' but nothing change always the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `latin1_swedish_ci` collation. I use this, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use Laragon, for change collation =

Right click > Maintenance > Change collation to latin5_turkish_ci